# Zend Framework Admin Module structure

Tags: php, mysql, security, zend-framework, admin

I am creating a large web application with Zend Framework 1.10. A am new in Zend Framework(1 month experiance). Can you explain me how to create a admin module in the best way?(with own authentication). How to make this with good security?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good practice is to create admin module with own controllers and plugins.

Comment: That depends on your packaging model. For example on a previous project we set up the basic Admin infrastructure with an Absctract Admin_Actions class, some front controller plugins and some action helpers. Then in every module there was an admin controller that extended the Admin_Actions class. But our application called for the easy installation/removal and packaging of modules.

Comment: For very basic applications, this works... for larger ones I'd say it's better practice to have all your modules (ex: blogs, cms, etc.) self-contained, each with their own admin controllers.  Then it's easier to re-use them in other projects.

Answer (score 2):

I would create `AdminController` in each module, then route rewriting the paths like this:

```
/admin/module1 => module1/AdminController
/admin/module2 => module2/AdminController
```

Then leverage [Zend_Auth](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.html) and [Zend_Acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html).

You will also need controller plugin which checks the credentials from `Zend_Auth` and a Authorization controller with login form.

But it all depends on your application.

Comment: Yes. It is good. But I think that iy is not a best solution. I will have a lot of same controllers in all modules. Thank you for help.

Comment: @Alexander Better yet. Just make them extend one base abstract.